# How to check if php-fpm is installed and running correctly?

Tags: php

As in title, how to check php-fpm status? Is it running? How many request serving? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the SAPI with

- [`php_sapi_name`](http://php.net/php_sapi_name) — Returns the type of interface between web server and PHP

> Returns the interface type, as a lowercase string.
>   Although not exhaustive, the possible return values include aolserver, apache, apache2filter, apache2handler, caudium, cgi (until PHP 5.3), cgi-fcgi, cli, continuity, embed, isapi, litespeed, milter, nsapi, phttpd, pi3web, roxen, thttpd, tux, and webjames.

For status and how many requests are served you might want to use `exec` or `system`.

Answer (score 8):

Is `ps -ef | grep php-fpm` too simple an answer for the first part?

You could also use the ping feature that you can enable with the [`ping.path` configuration directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#ping.path).

The second part can be achieved with the [`pm.status_path` configuration directive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#pm.status-path) that gives you access to a number of statistics, including the number of accepted connections.