# Start process in bash script after other process has started up

Tags: php, bash, nginx, containers

I'm trying to create a bash script that starts two processes: PHP-FPM and Nginx.

First PHP-FPM should start and once that has finished starting up (port 9000 will then be reachable for example, but there might be other means of checking it has finished starting up) the Nginx server should be started.

My current script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

php-fpm -F &
nginx &

wait -n
```

But sometimes early on nginx will give me a 502 gateway error because php-fpm is not ready yet.

What's the cleanest/best way of getting this startup in order?

Regards,

Kees.

Comment: Why do you use `php-fpm -F &`? `-F` force the process to stay in foreground, `&` make it run in background.

Comment: I suggest to strip down your script to: `php-fpm -F && nginx`

Comment: The -F is needed in my container @FrancescoLucianò I'm using Tini to make sure the container is killed when either php-fpm or nginx is stopping

Comment: @keesvanbemmel : Please specify what you mean by _finished_. Should the `php-fpm` be **terminated** (in which case you could simply write `php-fpm; nginx`, or should it stay running, and you just want to know whether the startup phase is over and the process can accept services? I think you mean the latter, but from the words you are using, it is not clear to me.

Comment: @user1934428 you are right, the latter is true: the startup phase is over and the process accepts services on port 9000. Sorry I wasn't clear

Comment: @keesvanbemmel : Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091647/how-to-check-if-php-fpm-is-installed-and-running-correctly) answer your question? Otherwise, the brute foce way would be to run `ngnix` in a loop, until you don't get an error message anymore.

Comment: it might @user1934428 but I don't know how to add that sapi call to my bash script?

Comment: @keesvanbemmel : Well, in a loop, you run php_sapi, until you get a reasonable answer. Since I have never used it, maybe you try it first manually, to see what responses you get in the good and bad case, and how failure is communicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your script in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

php-fpm -F && nginx

wait -n
```

As you can see in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators) on Unix&Linux, the `&&` operator allows you to run the second command only if the first exited successfully.

Comment: Thanks but the first one should not exit at all, it should keep running

Comment: @keesvanbemmel okay, I misunderstood your "First PHP-FPM should start and once that is ***finished***"

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't clear. Have updated the original quetion.